# how can output data from a rawfile or svg?

Tags: python, svg, netlist, raw-file

there! I'm using Ngspice to do circuit simulations. and plot a vector,but i don't know how to export data from an svg or raw file.The circuit is like below.[image]

and the netlist is below

```
ivdd 0 nd_pkg_pad 0 ac 1.0
.ac dec 100 10meg 10g
.save vm(nd_pkg_pad)
.control
set filetype=ascii
run
plot vm(nd_pkg_pad) xlog ylog
.endc
.end
```

Then run the netlist on Linux 20.04
The command is

```
ngspice
ngspice-> source circuit1.sp
```

Then it outputs a plot as below:

[image]

it can be saved in SVG format. but I wanna know how to extract data from this plot and export it to excel like choosing 1000 points of frequency and their corresponding voltage value.

it's better to use python code because a lot of plots to be handled.Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I know nothing about `ngspice`  but maybe https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/228868 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/551909

Comment: wow!That works!!!THANK YOU! it exports to a text then i can use python to read .

Comment: Glad it workedfor you. Maybe consider adding an answer to help other folks see how it looks/works.

Answer (score 1):

The method to transform voltage plot to data is using "wrdata"
for example,in a .cir or .sp file ,a circuit netlist file,the command is:

wrdata  filename(like test.txt) vm(node1)

<----(vm represent voltage,and node1 is a node name)

then test.txt will be generated and you can see the voltage data when do ac analysis.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).